# How to append only new rows with sheet_append in googlesheets within a shiny app

Tags: r, google-sheets, shiny, google-sheets-formula

This is not a reproducible example question!

**What I am doing:**
I use `library(googlesheets4)` to read a sheet from google sheets, entry data to it within a shiny app, and save it back to the sheet on google sheets.

I managed to read the data from google sheets with authentication etc...

So now I am having a google sheet say `my_sheet`.

I load the data from google sheets with

```
responses <- read_sheet("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/...etc... xx. and so on")
```

I can see the data in my app table now.

Now I add new data (rows) in my app and create new rows.

So far it is working perfect!

**Now I want to update the `my_sheet` in google sheets.**

I do:

```
# Click "Save" button -> save data
observeEvent(input$save, {
  my_sheet <- gs4_get("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/..bla bla bla")
  sheet_append(my_sheet, data = responses)
})
```

The data is written to the google sheet, but all of the data is appended not only the new entries.

So the data on google sheets in my_sheet is duplicated + the new rows, doubling each time I hit the save button.

**How can I keep my workflow and append only the new entries to google sheets.**

Comment: Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Do you need the information in the previous rows at all to generate the new rows? Sounds like responses should be just the last rows rather than loading previous rows and appending the new rows to them.